# How to pass the parameter from dataview dropdown webpart to chart webpart

Tags: data-view-web-part

I have a dataview dropdown webpart and the chart webpart in my page. I have to filter the values of the chart webpart depending on the value selected in the dropdown. I have done this using webpart connection it works well. But in the case of dropdown it's not possible. So how can i pass the parameter to the chart webpart from the dropdown.

Can anyone give solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Can you use JavaScript to get at the list selection, and then raise a client-side event?

There is a [Code Project article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/autoselect.aspx) on using JavaScript to handle list selections.